# I'm trying to make a discord bot that sends a joke from an API whenever a new user joins the server

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I can't seem to find a solution, every time I run the bot, and join the server on an alt account I get an error, that I can't fix. Here's my current code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import requests
import json

# import bot token
from apikeys import *


intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix="!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("the bot is now ready for use")
    print("--------------------")


@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello, I am PineKone")


@client.command()
async def roll(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.randint(1, 6))


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    url = "https://jokeapi-v2.p.rapidapi.com/joke/Any"

    querystring = {
        "format": "json",
        "contains": "C%23",
        "idRange": "0-150",
        "blacklistFlags": "nsfw,racist",
    }

    headers = {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": JOKEAPI,
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "jokeapi-v2.p.rapidapi.com",
    }

    response = requests.request(
        "GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring
    )

    # await member.send("Hello, and welcome to my (kone's) bot testing server!")
    channel = client.get_channel(1030862181195055148)
    # await channel.send("Hello, and welcome to my bot testing server!"
    await channel.send(json.loads(response.text)["joke"])


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(1030862181195055148)
    await channel.send("Sad to see you go...")


client.run(BOTTOKEN)
```

And Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\Discort Bot\main.py", line 55, in on_member_join
    await channel.send(json.loads(response.text)["joke"])
KeyError: 'joke'
```

I managed to make it work partially, but the only output I'm getting is this:

```
{'error': False, 'category': 'Programming', 'type': 'twopart', 'setup': 'Why do programmers wear glasses?', 'delivery': 'Because they need to C#', 'flags': {'nsfw': False, 'religious': False, 'political': False, 'racist': False, 'sexist': False, 'explicit': False}, 'id': 50, 'safe': True, 'lang': 'en'}
```

And then you have single part jokes, which returned:

```
{'error': False, 'category': 'Programming', 'type': 'single', 'joke': "Hey Girl,\nRoses are #ff0000,\nViolets are #0000ff,\nI use hex codes,\nBut I'd use RGB for you.", 'flags': {'nsfw': False, 'religious': False, 'political': False, 'racist': False, 'sexist': False, 'explicit': False}, 'id': 41, 'safe': True, 'lang': 'en'}
```

Anyone got a solution, or faced the same problem and managed to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since not all responses evidently have the `'joke'` key, but `'setup'` and `'delivery'`, you'll need to do something like

```
resp = json.loads(response.text)
if "joke" in resp:
    await channel.send(resp["joke"])
elif "setup" in resp and "delivery" in resp:
    await channel.send(resp["setup"])
    await channel.send(resp["delivery"])
```

If you want, you could add an `await asyncio.sleep(1)` between the setup and delivery...

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking about putting it in a loop, but couldn't figure out how to exactly do it. Your solution works, and I get no errors now, however the bot seems to be sending the same joke over and over. I tried 3 times, and got the exact same C# joke. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, the bot does obviously request a new joke every time. Are you sure there are multiple C# jokes available over that API?

Comment: Well, the API id range for jokes is 0-150, so it shouldn't really send the same one 3 times in a row. I'm considering changing the API to be honest.

Comment: What if you get rid of the `idRange`? I mean, what if there are more jokes about C# but only one with an ID in that range?